# Any String concat with previous one not showing VB.NET

Tags: vb.net, string-concatenation, tcpserver

Okay, so this is a very basic problem i guess, i'm not sure what's wrong with my code. Any string/character i concat with another string (ClientName) is not showing. In fact it just removes any other character after ClientName.

Here is the code:

Public Sub Chat()

```
    While Link.Client.Connected

        Try

            NumberOfMessages = NumberOfMessages + 1 'Update number of clients.

            Stream = Link.GetStream 'Get the stream from Socket.

            Dim MessageIn, MessageOut As String

            MessageIn = GetDataFromStream(Stream)

            ClientName = GetClientName_Stream(MessageIn)

            MessageBox.Show(ClientName & "****") 'Here **** is removed :-/

            MainForm.UpdateMessage(ClientName & ">> " & MessageIn)


            MessageOut = MessageIn 'Echo Back same message

            SendDataFromStream(Stream, MessageOut)

        Catch e As Exception
        End Try
    End While
End Sub
```

And Here is the Function that extracts the name from the received message:

Private Function GetClientName_Stream(ByVal msg As String) As String

```
    Dim pos As Integer
    pos = msg.LastIndexOf("$")
    Dim name As String

    name = msg.Substring(pos + 1)
    Return name
End Function
```

The client sends the message in this format:

**Hello World$TheClientName**

Where TheClientName is the name of that client.

And this is the GetDataFromStream function:

Private Function GetDataFromStream(Stream As NetworkStream) As String

```
    Dim Buffer(2000) As Byte 'The buffer in which the data will be stored in form of Bytes.
    Dim SizeOfData As Integer = Buffer.Length 'Link.ReceiveBufferSize 'The size of Buffer to read.
    Dim TheData As String 'The Data received from Stream.




    Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, SizeOfData) 'Read the Stream and store it in Buffer.

    TheData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer) 'Create String from Buffer.



    Return TheData
End Function
```

Comment: I misinterpreted the question so I have deleted my previous answer and will add a new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is that you are converting the entire `Byte` array to a `String` when only part of the array was populated from the `Stream`.  That means that your `String` has null characters at the end of it.  If you append text to that `String` then the `String` object will contain those characters but, when you display it, only what comes before the first null character will be displayed.  The issue is here:

```
Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, SizeOfData)

TheData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer)
```

What you need to do is determine how many `Byte`s were read on the first line and then only convert that many `Byte`s to a `String` in the second:

```
Dim bytesRead = Stream.Read(Buffer, 0, SizeOfData)

TheData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(Buffer, 0, bytesRead)
```

That way, all the zero `Byte`s in the part of the array that wasn't written to will not be converted to null characters.